# Excel (Mac) 2020 version ... Contant Error 400 messages ... any idea why?

Tags: excel, runtime-error, save-as

I am trying to export a sheet within a workbook as a CSV file. I cannot see any export functions for a sheet. After casting around, it seem that a work around involves creating a new workbook, pasting there and saving that as a CSV.

When I use the .copy method on my sheet, Excel creates a new workbook.
I can access that new workbook in the code below, but *the SaveAs line is generating an error 400*. I have permissions to write to the folder. Excel simply gives the error message 400. No other indicators. Searching online talks about missing modules (or similar) but mine is a new install and using what I take to be standard methods.

```
Dim TempWB As Workbook
Dim fileName As String

fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/theCSV.csv"
Sheets("theCSV").Copy
 
Set TempWB = ActiveWorkbook
 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TempWB.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Thanks

Comment: The first thing I'd try is changing the name of your `fileName` variable, as it may be confusing things in the `SaveAs fileName:=fileName` line. Did you try either using a different name for that variable or simply hard-coding the filename in the `SaveAs filename:=` line to see if that solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

@Ken White Thanks for that ... bad coding on my part ...

I changed the variable name and still saw the 400 error messages.

Then I thought, this being MS etc., are they playing lip service again towards Mac compatibility. From my Mac I used an RDS link to a W10 PC running Excel ... no errors!!! These errors seem to relate to code being run on a Mac rather than the via code itself.

Within the RDS, I have a mapped drive directly to my Mac and ran the code using the mapped drive ... i.e. I was writing directly to my Macs folders from Excel in the RDS ... no problems. It does not seem to be an OS permissions thing.

For me, this is a work around, if you have a RDS/VM available.